# HTML5 Canvas not displaying text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm learning some game dev with JavaScript, so I wanted to use HTML5 canvas to draw on the screen. The problem is that I can't get it to display text.
You can see my code here (you might be greeted by a prompt asking a name for your chatracter) http://jsfiddle.net/LAmC3/

Essentially i only used:

```
canX.font = '80pt Helvetica';
canX.fillText(player.getName(),100, 100);
```

With canX being the context of my canvas which has the same dimensions as the viewport.

If anyone knows why, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

You're drawing the text in the same colour as the background, set the `fillStyle` to something new, e.g.

```
canX.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so dumb ^^